# Where can I find a database of xml files?

Tags: xml, database

I have to carry out a comparative analysis of storage methods based on the XML standard. But I don't know where I can find proper database.
I was looking in those pages:

[data.gov.uk](https://www.data.gov.uk/search?filters%5Bformat%5D=XML)

[uci](https://web.archive.org/web/20230605224621/https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php)

[kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/)

but the files I found are quite strange. They look more like txt files or the entire database contains only one xml file.

Do you know where else should I search and how such an XML database should look like?

Comment: Look for an xml file that was made from the DataSet.  A dataset xml file will have the name of the dataset as the root tag.  The next level tags are the names of each table.  The 3rd level tags contain the column names of each table and the 4th level tags of the xml are the row data.  If you make a DataSet manually and use the WriteXml method you can create your own.  I will post sample code

Answer (score 1):

The U.S. government site Data.Gov is a catalog of open data shared by the government in various formats. There are more than 34,000 datasets in XML that you can search by visiting [this page](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?res_format=XML).

Here's a snippet of XML from one dataset, [2010 Census Populations by Zip Code](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/2010-census-populations-by-zip-code).

```
<response>
    <row>
        <row _id="228" _uuid="A47815EC-0DA0-499D-9CE6-616A23C4F155" _position="228" _address="https://data.lacity.org/resource/nxs9-385f/228">
            <zip_code>91371</zip_code>
            <total_population>1</total_population>
            <median_age>73.5</median_age>
            <total_males>0</total_males>
            <total_females>1</total_females>
            <total_households>1</total_households>
            <average_household_size>1.00</average_household_size>
        </row>
        <row _id="1" _uuid="1AE8EAF5-D6E6-4AF9-88FD-3CF179F2A8FC" _position="1" _address="https://data.lacity.org/resource/nxs9-385f/1">
            <zip_code>90001</zip_code>
            <total_population>57110</total_population>
            <median_age>26.6</median_age>
            <total_males>28468</total_males>
            <total_females>28642</total_females>
            <total_households>12971</total_households>
            <average_household_size>4.40</average_household_size>
        </row>
    </row>
</response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("Name Table");
            dt1.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt1.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "John", 1234});
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Mary", 1235 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Jim", 1236 });
            dt1.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Rose", 1237 });

            ds.Tables.Add(dt1);

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable("Age Table");
            dt2.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(int));
            dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));

            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 20, 1234 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 30, 1235 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 40, 1236 });
            dt2.Rows.Add(new object[] { 50, 1237 });

            ds.Tables.Add(dt2);

            //with schema
            //ds.WriteXml(FILENAME, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
            //ithout schema
            ds.WriteXml(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is the output :

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<MyDataSet>
  <Name_x0020_Table>
    <Name>John</Name>
    <ID>1234</ID>
  </Name_x0020_Table>
  <Name_x0020_Table>
    <Name>Mary</Name>
    <ID>1235</ID>
  </Name_x0020_Table>
  <Name_x0020_Table>
    <Name>Jim</Name>
    <ID>1236</ID>
  </Name_x0020_Table>
  <Name_x0020_Table>
    <Name>Rose</Name>
    <ID>1237</ID>
  </Name_x0020_Table>
  <Age_x0020_Table>
    <Name>20</Name>
    <ID>1234</ID>
  </Age_x0020_Table>
  <Age_x0020_Table>
    <Name>30</Name>
    <ID>1235</ID>
  </Age_x0020_Table>
  <Age_x0020_Table>
    <Name>40</Name>
    <ID>1236</ID>
  </Age_x0020_Table>
  <Age_x0020_Table>
    <Name>50</Name>
    <ID>1237</ID>
  </Age_x0020_Table>
</MyDataSet>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to download a database from the Internet, which already has a lot of records and then just use it. I didn't want to create my own database.